# Can i wait for HTML5 FileSystem DirectoryReader before doing other functions?

Tags: html, filesystems

Im trying to use the new HTML5 FileSystem API for creating/adding/deleting files with javascript. (for use with a self-service cash desk)

current code:

```
var entries;
function onInitFs(fs) {
    fileSystem = fs;
    debug('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
    loadFilelist();
    // The functions below execute before loadFilelist() is ready!
    setFileList(entries);
    showFilenames(entries);
}

function loadFilelist() {
    entries = [];
    var dirReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    readEntries();

    function readEntries() {
        dirReader.readEntries(function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                debug(results.length + " Files added to the filesystemFilelist");
                entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
                entries.sort();
                readEntries();
            }else{
                debug(entries.length + " Files in the filesystemFilelist");
                //done
            }
        }, fileErrorHandler);
    };
}

/* For putting debug text in the debug screen (in this case its the console) */
function debug(content) {
    window.console.log(content);
}
```

The problem with this is that the function dirReader.readEntries(function (), callback) waits for a callback. Meanwhile the code that comes next already executes.
Ive looked it up in the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#the-directoryreader-interface) and it seems the function only works with a callback

How can i prevent that the function calls

```
setFileList(entries);
showFilenames(entries);
```

execute before loadFilelist is done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ohh it seems there is a Synchonous way to do it descibed [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#the-directoryentrysync-interface) Anyone who can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently im using a worker to do the synchronous work! Works perfect! I made a 'command system thingy' between the main and the worker scripts. **I will post the basics if someone is interested**! Barely anybody looked at this question so for now i only mark it as SOLVED

Comment: You should provide a code example here - in it's current form, this answer is helpful to exactly `0` people.

Answer (score 0):

Code example as requested by @Jimbo

**Code in the main javascript**

```
/**
 * Make a listener for the worker
 * 
 * @param {object}
 *            worker
 */
function workerListener(worker) {
    worker.onmessage = function(event) {
        switch (event.data.cmd) {
        case 'log':
            _Some_log_function(event.data.message);
            break;
        case 'error':
            _Some_error_handling(event.data.message, event.data.priority);
            break;
        case '_Some_command':
            _Some_function();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Sends a message to a worker
 * 
 * @param {Object}
 *            worker
 * @param {Object}
 *            message JSON Object
 */
function postMessage(worker, message) {
    /* send message to the worker */
    worker.postMessage(message);
}
```

**Code in the Worker javascript**

```
/**
 * Listener, Listens to messages from the main thread
 * 
 * @param {Object}
 *            event
 */
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    _log(event.data.cmd);
    switch (event.data.cmd) {
    case 'init':
        _Some_init_function(event.data.filesystemsize,
                event.data.directory);
        break;

    case '_Some_Sendingmeganism':
        sendMail(event.data.receipt, event.data.filename, event.data.email);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
};
```